# How to execute an INSERT that's in a SELECT statement?

Tags: oracle, dynamic, dynamic-sql, insert-select, select-insert

for my DB course i have a table: lab4Central which columns are: productid, description and plantid, 
The plant QRO has and id = 1000, an example: 12799, 'Product 12799', 1000.
and the plant SLP has an id = 2000, ex: 29665, 'Product 29665', 2000.

I have to add new registers for other 2 plants: GDA and MTY.
For GDA the registers are the same of the plant QRO but it has tu adjust the productid + 20000, the same for MTY but with the registers of SLP so at the end it will look like:

```
Plant GDA: 329799, 'Product 32799', 3000.
plant MTY: 49665, 'Product 49665', 4000.
```

AS you can see for GDA the register is the same of the one in QRO but another plantid and we add 20000 to the productid, the same for MTY.

I code this which give me the correct values:

```
SELECT  'INSERT INTO LAB4CENTRAL VALUES('||(PRODUCTID+20000) || ',' || DESCRIPTION || ','|| 3000 ||');' FROM LAB4CENTRAL WHERE PLANTID=1000;
```

But it's just a select and i don't know how to execute the insert statement so it insert the data in the table.

hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL? Because pipelines (to string concat) isn't really support by MySQL without a enabled sql_mode.

Comment: Hmmm yes, i'm using sqlplus and sql developer.

Comment: sqlplus and sql developer are Oracle database not MySQL database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want insert the select result in the column  ProductId , Description and your_col_fro_3000
You could use a INSERT SELECT

```
    INSERT INTO LAB4CENTRAL(ProductID, Description, your_col_for_3000) 
    SELECT ProductID + 20000, 'Product' || (Productid + 20000), 3000 
    FROM LAB4CENTRAL 
    WHERE PlantID = 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually the opposite of what you wrote. Instead an [Insert... Select...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) is probably what you are after.

```
INSERT INTO LAB4CENTRAL 
SELECT ProductID + 20000, 'Product' || Productid + 20000, 3000 
FROM LAB4CENTRAL 
WHERE PlantID = 1000;
```

That may need to be tweaked to fit your data, but the basic idea is to write a SELECT statement that gives you the result set that you then want to insert into the table.

Answer (score 0):

It can very well be a trick to generate INSERT statements that then manually are executed, maybe in batches of circa 100 lines.

Otherwise one would do an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. But that is not possible for the **same table**, hence this solution.

See also OUTPUT TO FILE or such (I do not know at this moment).